# How can I to transmit at least a "couple of bytes" on the local network (UEFI DXE)

Tags: networking, driver, uefi

I need to write driver (DXE), that can transmit "couple of bytes" from virtual machine (QEMU) to the host system (OS - Ubuntu). I've read the UEFI_Spec and Guide for developers, but I still don't understand, how to write the code and what protocol should I use (tried to use TCPv4 but can't even LocateHandleBuffer).

```
EFI_STATUS Status = gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtocol, &gEfiTcp4ProtocolGuid, NULL, &HandleCount, &HandleBuffer);
```

I get:

```
EFI_UNSUPPORTED
```

If somebody can explain me or can show examples of the code, I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ivan - Please dont't use slang or chat abbreviations as some people might not understand.

Answer (score 1):

For most network related protocols you first have to use the corresponding "Service Binding Protocol" to get a handle which contains the protocol you are looking for.

Use this steps to access the Tcp4Protocol:

```
gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtovol,gEfiTcp4ServiceBindingProtocolGuid, NULL, &HandleCount, &HandleBuffer);
// Loop over the HandleBuffer Array and pick the one you need
gBS->HandleProtocol(HandleBuffer[YourIndex], &gEfiTcp4ServiceBindingProtocolGuid, &Tcp4SBProtocol);
Tcp4SBProtocol->CreateChild(Tcp4SBProtocol, &Tcp4Handle);
gBS->HandleProtocol(Tcp4Handle, &gEfiTcp4ProtocolGuid, &Tcp4Protocol);
```

To check if a NIC is available you can use:

```
// This should return EFI_SUCCESS
gBS->LocateProtocol(&gEfiSimpleNetworkProtocolGuid, NULL, &SimpleNetworkProtocol);
```

There is a complete code sample for the HttpProtocol inside the [Uefi specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf) (starting at page 1548), the Tcp4Protocol is not very different.

Comment: Same I should do for the http protocol?

Comment: The procedure is the same for all network related protocols (TCP, MNP, UDP,...) (the exception to the rule is the SimpleNetworkProtocol), first get the ServiceBindingProtocol and then use it to get a protocol instance.
The Uefi specification contains a complete HTTP sample.

Comment: I've tried to load this example and i've got:   EFI_NOT_FOUND in function LocateProtocol(). So why http protocol can't be found. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Boot into an efishell and make sure you have drivers for all layers of the networkstack (use the "drivers" command to list all available drivers).
If the driver names match the ones from edk2 there should be at least the following drivers: SnpDxe, MnpDxe, Ip4Dxe, Udp4Dxe, DnsDxe, Dhcp4Dxe, TcpDxe, HttpUtilitiesDxe and HttpDxe and the should all be connected to a network device.
If some of them are missing you can build the edk2 NetworkPkg and load the drivers from the shell or your application.